# Как построить астропроцессор?

Tags: карты

Хочу сделать конструктор натальной карты.

Вот библиотека на гитхаб
https://github.com/chapagain/php-swiss-ephemeris

Пример  запуска https://watch4free.ru/23/natal.php

Пример реализации https://astrostudiya.ru/horoscope-create/

Из скрипта гита

> ```
> $birthDate = new DateTime( '09 August 2017 21:35:00');
> $latitude = 27.7172453;
> $longitude = 85.3239605;
> $timezone = 5.75;
> ```

Вот данные для формы что вводил по координатам гита

> ```
> Дата рождения 09.08.2017 21:35
> Катманду, парк Королевского Дворца
> ```

Но результат отличается от того что скрипт с гита выдает https://prnt.sc/FhBCJFtMhMeh Рассположение небесных тел отличается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вопрос в чем? что не так работает? какого результат хотите достичь?

Comment: Например хотелось бы достичь совпадения с дом 1 по дом 12 с тем что рисмскими цифрами (на рисунке) прописано в градусах отличается

Comment: Для создания гороскопов и тому подобной фигни достаточно освоить генератор случайных чисел.